# Handling Trim on migration to .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have an application which has been migrated from VB to VB.NET. In VB code Trim function has been used on the values from database,in lots of places.As VB Trim can propagate NULL no error is thrown. Now when the code is migrated to .NET same Trim functions are are throwing errors as it doesn't support NULL propagation in .NET.How I can address this issue on changing my code in a single place? It will be a tedious job if I have to use Convert.ToString for all places. Any out of the box suggession? Databse is DB2

```
 Sample:
   VB:
   res = Trim(rs("Name").Value)
    num = Len(rs("Name").Value)

   Converted VB.NET Code
   rs("Name").Trim()
   rs("Name").Length
```

Comment: Can u post a sample line that works in VB6 but throws an error in VB.NET?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the converted code to let us know what your dealing with? I don't think there is a 'single place' fix for this, but a clever find and replace could go a long ways to help.

Comment: sure: res = Trim(rs("Name").Value)
        num = Len6(rs("Name").Value)

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: Do you also have many different queries that return data or this number is fairly small?

Comment: There are lots of queries

Comment: VB.NET has VB6-style `Trim` function that allows `Nothing` as the parameter. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 4):

`DBNull.ToString` returns an empty string. So do a Global Find/Replace for

`.Trim(`

to

`.ToString().Trim(`

Comment: Then I have touch allover.Can I do in a single place?

Comment: Yes it will be all over, but fully automatic and very fast replace. Any particular reason this is not desirable? You already did all-over replace during conversion, this is just one more addition

Answer (score 0):

Create a module and create  a public function ad follows:

```
Public function IfNull(ByVal oObj as Object, byval oRetVal as Object) as Object
    If oObj = Nothing orelse oObj = dbvalue.null then
       Return oRetval
    End if

    Try
       Return oObj.ToString.Trim()
    Catch ex as exception
    End try
End function
```

I am with mobile,when I have my laptop I will try to make it better

You know what you need but for me to cast everything to String is not the best practice...